# iOS Scrolling Parallax Effect in Table View Cell Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I create Scrolling Parallax Effect in Table View Cell in my project but i have some freeze when i scrolling.

My code in custom Table View Cell :

```
class newsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageNews: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageTop: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imageNews.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Code in my Main View Controller:

```
var paralaxOfSetSpeed: CGFloat = 70
var cellHeignt: CGFloat = 170

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! newsTableViewCell

    let good = data[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLable.text = (good["title"] as! String)
    cell.imageHeight.constant = paralaxImageHeight
    cell.imageTop.constant = paralaxOfSet(newOfSetY: tableView.contentOffset.y, cell: cell)

    let newsImage = good["image"] as! PFFile

    newsImage.getDataInBackground{ (imageData, error) in
        if imageData != nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.imageNews.image = image
        } else {
            print(error ?? "getDataInBackground error")
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func paralaxOfSet(newOfSetY: CGFloat, cell: UITableViewCell) -> CGFloat {
    return (newOfSetY - cell.frame.origin.y) / paralaxImageHeight * paralaxOfSetSpeed
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let ofSetY = tableView.contentOffset.y
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [newsTableViewCell] {
        cell.imageTop.constant = paralaxOfSet(newOfSetY: tableView.contentOffset.y, cell: cell)
    }
}

var paralaxImageHeight: CGFloat {
    let maxOffSet = (sqrt(pow(cellHeignt, 2) + 4 * paralaxOfSetSpeed * self.tableView.frame.height ) - cellHeignt) / 1.5
    return maxOffSet + self.cellHeignt
}
```

This is my code, main problem it's scrolling because it's a not smooth.
**UPDATE:**
So in the end, i want to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi there. How many times is scrollViewDidScroll being called (perhaps add a console log as a quick and dirty check)? I suspect the problem is that you are iterating over the whole collection view each time it is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into the below libraries:

They have implemented the parallax view in `TableViewCell`

1. https://github.com/marty-suzuki/SAParallaxViewControllerSwift

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, i try this before i wrote question